# How to Ensure proper initialization of Non Static Data Members within a Class Template in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, initialization, c++17

I am working with templates in C++ and want to know how can we properly(value) initialize the non static data members in a class template. For example, consider the following snippet:

```
template<typename T>
class MyVector
{
    T x; // x has undefined value for a built in type
};
```

Now i know that the data member `x` has **garbage value** for built in types in local/block scope unless explicitly initialized.

So i want to value initialize the data member. If i modify the above code to:

```
template<typename T>
class MyVector
{
    T x(); // now x becomes a member function 
};
```

As can be seen in the above modified code snippet, `x` is now a member function. How can i **value initialize** the data member `x` for type `T`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different way to do what you want depending upon which C++ version you're using. This is explained in more detail below:

#### C++11

```
template<typename T>
class MyVector
{
    T x{}; 
};
```

#### Pre C++11

```
template<typename T>
class MyVector
{
    T x;
    MyVector(): x()
    {
    }
};
```

#### C++11

From C++11 and onwards, you can also write(using **constructor initializer list)**:

```
template<typename T>
class MyVector
{
    T x;
    MyVector(): x{}
    {
    }
};
```

#### C++11

Note that this version [**won't work if**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lW0JPjtAhjmJbBNg) the constructor for copy initialization is **explicit** since there is no mandatory **copy elison**.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
struct Name 
{
    explicit Name(const Name&)
  {
      
  }
  Name() = default;
};
template<typename T>
class MyVector
{
    public:
    T x = T();
    
};
int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World";
    MyVector<int> p; // works with C++11,C++17 etc
    MyVector<Name> n; //error with C++11 and C++14
    return 0;
}
```

But the above version [will work](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CsTdEsQxkTyjb1QK) with C++17 since there is **mandatory copy elison** in C++17.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
struct Name 
{
    explicit Name(const Name&)
  {
      
  }
  Name() = default;
};
template<typename T>
class MyVector
{
    public:
    T x = T();
    
};
int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World";
    MyVector<int> p; // works with C++11,C++17 etc
    MyVector<Name> n; //works with C++17 due to mandatory copy elison
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [default member initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) (since C++11), which only supports equal-sign or braced initializer, but not parentheses one.

```
template<typename T>
class MyVector
{
    T x{};
    // or
    T x = T();
};
```

Or provide a user-defined constructor with member initializer list.

```
template<typename T>
class MyVector
{
    T x;
    MyVector() : x() {}
};
```