# Use of parenthesis or curly braces in C++ constructor initializer list

Tags: c++, list, constructor, initializer

I have a question on constructor initializer list as follows :
while specifying the initial values of members, initial values are written in ()- parenthesis according to C++ Primer book (author - Stanley Lippman). However, I have also seen {} being used to specify initial values (please refer to link - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor)
can someone explain when to use  () - parenthesis and when to use {} - curly braces
thanks and regards,
-sunil puranik

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Different ways of initializing an object in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49802012/different-ways-of-initializing-an-object-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

According to Scott meyors Effective Modern C++, Item 7, you should basically be using `{}` wherever you can in the initializer list. If you are initialising a type that takes a `std::initializer_list` then you will need to think about it a bit more. But outside of `std::vector` and templates, you should basically always be using `{}` to construct. Why? From Scott Meyors:

> Braced initialization is the most widely usable initialization syntax, it prevents
> narrowing conversions, and it’s immune to C++’s most vexing parse.

Comment: Scott Meyers! Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using `T x{};` where `T` is some type, is called **zero initialization**.

Parenthesis `()` is **Pre-C++11** while braces `{}` is from **C++11** and onwards(like c++11, c++14, etc). This is just one of the many differences between the two.
For example,

#### Pre C++11

```
class MyVector
{
    int x;
    MyVector(): x()
    {
    }
};
```

#### C++11

From C++11 and onwards, you can use `{}` instead as shown below:

```
class MyVector
{
    int x;
    MyVector(): x{}
    {
    }
};
```

In the *context* of **constructor initializer list**(which is what your question is about) they are used to **ensure proper initialization** of non-static data members of a class template as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70365084/how-to-ensure-proper-initialization-of-non-static-data-members-within-a-class-te/70365145#70365145).

Comment: @SunilPuranik You're welcome. For why they are needed you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70365084/how-to-ensure-proper-initialization-of-non-static-data-members-within-a-class-te/70365145#70365145) .